# Identifying some hair, a green "gem", and white minifigures accessory

Tags: part-identification, clone-brands

I recently acquired a few pounds of LEGO with some off-brand building blocks mixed through it. I've got three mystery pieces that I haven't been able to find on Bricklink.  I'm wondering if they are Lego or off-brand pieces. I was under the impression that most LEGO pieces had the word LEGO written on them, and none of these do.

1. Brown hair: Has the number 5 on the bottom.  It fits a 2x2 square.  I got no matches in a search for "hair", filtering to brown color.
   [image: Top of hair]
   [image: Bottom or hair]
2. Green gem: It kind of reminds me of Rock Raiders, but I got no matches for "green gem" or "green jewel".  The base is a 2x2 circle. It has no lettering on it.
   [image: Top of gem]
   [image: Bottom of gem]
3. White "wings"? This one I am quite sceptical of, however it fits perfectly on a minifigure as a pair of wings.  I had no idea what to search for this one.  It has a number 2 on it.
   [image: Front of wings]
   [image: Back of wings]

I'd like to know if these are Lego pieces.  Reasons that they likely aren't (eg. LEGO has never used that color) are great too.

Comment: Not sure about first element, but the last to are definitely not LEGO.

Comment: Your photos are very clear. It's my opinion that none are Lego parts. The parts are large enough to have Lego trademarks but none are appearant in your pictures. The molding quality of the green crystal seems far short of what Lego produces.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Piece 1 is Mega Bloks. Here's is a picture of a head (twice) that goes with it, and some yellow hair as well. [image: Mega Bloks]

Comment: And now Lego has their own brick which is very similar to that head: <https://cdn.rebrickable.com/media/thumbs/parts/elements/6382134.jpg/250x250p.jpg?1659323220.083711>

Answer (score 7):

The bottom piece seems to be Kre-O — this is a LEGO-like product produced by Hasbro, which includes a number of sets based on the Transformers franchise (which Hasbro also own).

This piece can be seen on the 3rd character (a "Kreon", their version of a Minifig) in the 6th row of the below image.

[image: Kre-O Transformers Kreon figures]

Comment: Fantastic, thanks!  I could have sworn that that piece was supposed to be car doors, I just couldn't understand why. Now I know.